# Windows 10/11 pending files to be indexed

Tags: windows-11, search-indexing

Is there a way to see which files are pending to be indexed?

In Windows 11 settings > Privacy & Security > Searching Windows, the Indexed Status indicates the number of indexed and pending files. Every now and then, Window's indexer kicks in and uses a lot CPU. The [number of pending files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4WEn.jpg) changes a lot, but the number of indexed files do not. I know I'm not editing 40 - 50 files for that to be happening. I would like to see the list of files that is causing this indexing problem in order to find out what the problem is.

I already tried to rebuild the index and ran the troubleshooting, none of them made a difference. There is a possibility for this to be caused by Bitdefender or Google Drive, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I do not believe there is any such list.  Set up to index, do this in the evening, and let the machine run overnight. Indexing should be complete next morning. Control Panel, Index Options will say Indexing Complete.